# Modular TCRM App Template to allow reuse and configuration

Tags: einstein-analytics, isv, crm-analytics

Are there any best practices for keeping TCRM Template Apps modular and flexible?

I want to add a template app to my Managed Package but allow Subscribers to reshuffle and adapt it.

So instead of a single clunky and hard-to-modify Dashboard Monolith, I want to create small reusable artifacts that can be used separately or recombined without breaking immediately.

Are there recommendations on how to structure:

- Recipes
- Data Flows
- Lenses
- Dashboards
- Components

so that subscribers can adapt and customize them most flexibly?

Many sample dashboards look quite clunky and monolithic, and I imagine it to be hard for subscribers to adapt them even if they have full access.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions. A template does not need to include everything in it. I consider the Recipes and Datasets like I would a reusable utility class in APEX. This template can be auto-installed, or build a template wizard to allow the user to customize what is in the datasets. Now you have an App setup, Recipes and Dataflows, and your working set of datasets.

Then the Dashboards are all built to use this standard set of datasets, and the users can use your creation template over and over again to make versions of the dashboards, lenses etc.

Another benefit of this is that the users can use the Utility Template to create different versions of the data, say targets towards different regions, or user personas.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to package analytics artifacts is via Analytics templates. You can find more information on how to create templates [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_create_manage_templates_intro.htm&type=5). Users can create apps from the templates while answering the personalization wizard. For example, the user can decide the type of dashboard (e.g. line chart vs pie chart), colors, and which object and fields to use to build the dashboards during app creation. https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00006YKmQk
is the webinar recording where our engineering team discusses the best practices.

Comment: I know the part with the templates. Would you mind summarizing a few of the best practices related to my question in your answer so other people can make use out of it without Partner community access?